# Contact Form - How to display the contents of error message array in body of the form's html

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, contact-form

This is my first time trying to use php in a website and posting a question to stackoverflow. I hope I haven't posted too much code.

The goal is to have the results of a `foreach` loop display an array's content in the form's html. I'm have been able to display one error message, but not more than one when several exist. Currently the code returns 'Array' when submitted with errors.

```
   <?php
$to = "companyname@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $nam = strip_tags($_POST["name"]);
    $ema = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $msg = strip_tags($_POST["message"]);

$error_msg=array(); //initiate array, not required

if (empty($nam) || !preg_match("/^[\s.'\-\pL]{1,60}$/u", $nam)) { 
$error_msg[] = "<p>Please fill in your name with only letters, spaces and    basic punctuation (.&nbsp;-&nbsp;')</p>";
}

if (empty($ema) || !filter_var($ema, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error_msg[] = "<p>Your email must have a valid format, such as emailname@mailhost.com</p>";
}

$limit = 1500; 

if (empty($msg) || !preg_match("/^[0-9\/\-\_\s'\(\)\@!\?\.,:;\pL]+$/u", $msg) || (strlen($msg) > $limit)) { 
$error_msg[] = "<p>The Message field must contain only letters, digits, spaces and basic punctuation (&nbsp;'&nbsp;-&nbsp;,&nbsp;.&nbsp;:&nbsp;;&nbsp;/ and parentheses), and has a limit of 1500 characters</p>";
}

$body = 
    "Name of sender: $nam\n\n" .
    "Email of sender: $ema\n\n" .
    "Message:\n\n" .
    "$msg" ; 

$body = wordwrap($body, 70);

$headers = "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: <$ema>\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $nam <$ema>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender: $ema\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP" . phpversion() . "\r\n";

if ($error_msg) {

foreach ($error_msg as $error_output) {

$error_msg_list .= '<div class="error">' . $error_output . '</div>';

}
// if no errors, send the email
} else if (!$error_msg) {
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
$success_output = "Your message has been sent. We will get back to you shortly.";
$_POST = array();  //clears the form data after valid form submission
} 
} //end isset
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <?php
      if (isset($error_msg_list)) { 
       echo  $error_msg_list;   
       } else { 
        echo "<div class='success'>" . $success_output . "</div>";} 
    ?>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="your name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["name"])) {echo $nam;} ?>">      
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="your email address" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["email"])) {echo $ema;} ?>">
        </div>      
        <div>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" id="message"><?php if (isset($_POST["message"])) {echo $msg;} ?></textarea>
        </div>              
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain the foreach loop that will iterate through every element, etc...? $error_msg is already an array of error messages.

Comment: @Luke  The foreach loop will iterate through $error_msg[] and then I could use echo to list all occurrences of validation errors, ie $error_msg. This does work, but puts the results at the top of the html inside the body element and I'm trying to have those results echo as part of the isset() to print $error_msg or $success_msg  inside the form element. Currently having $error_msg in the isset() returns 'Array' and not the list upon submission of the form.

Answer (score 0):

The Code is write you have done this

```
 foreach ($error_msg as $error_output) {
   $error_msg[] = $error_output;
 }
```

OR do this

```
foreach ($error_msg as $error_output) {
   echo "<div class='error'>". $error_output . "</div>";
 }
```

Or do this

Instead Do this

```
$message = array();
foreach ($error_msg as $error_output) {
       $message['key_you_want_or_use_indexing'] "<div class='error'>". $error_output . "</div>";
 }
 echo $message[0]; // for first error
```

if the array have messages it will show them one by one in each line

Comment: Is there a way to have the foreach loop create the div.error inside the form element the same way as $success_output?

Comment: Can the 'do something' part of the foreach() create an result/container that can be used and not echoed as a list until form submission, therefore being able to include the 'do something' part in the isset() located in the form element?

Comment: yes initialize the variable,  create the container or result and store it in a variable, then use the variable where ever you want, if there are multiple results, then use array instead of variable and define it keys so that you will have separate messages

Comment: Should there be an '=' after ['key_you_want...'] ?

Comment: I tried -  $message[0] = "<div class='error'>" . $error_output . "</div>"; and  in the html if (isset($error_msg_list)) { 
 echo  $error_msg_list[0]; 
 } else { 
 echo "<div class='success'>" . $success_output . "</div>";} and it returned the last error_msg_list but not all three.

Comment: Your trying wrong if you assign the default key in $messages as 0 if will push its value, on same key for the whole loop your key should not be static

Answer (score 0):

> I edited the code to add a .= in the foreach loop which created all three variables

```
if ($error_msg) {
  foreach ($error_msg as $error_output) {
    $error_msg_list .= '<div class="error">' . $error_output . '</div>';
}
```

> I changed the php in the form element to use $error_msg_list

```
<?php
  if (isset($error_msg_list)) { 
  echo  $error_msg_list;    
  } else { 
  echo "<div class='success'>" . $success_output . "</div>";}   
?>
```